# group queries running frequently drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, group

I'm checking `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` in MySQL
Group queries running too much
In this getting all fields data in group, i attached queries with pastebin file

https://pastebin.com/raw/TUvUj60Z
https://pastebin.com/raw/4BY3HAHT

i just want to remove these all extra queries to improve page speed
i try to clean code and optimize contrib module data but not working

Comment: Can you cache the results?